# How to echo/print within a fuction with undefined variables in php?

Tags: php

I am not the best at php but currently I am trying to learn. I can print fine outside of the function but the specific instructions I have been given require me to print the results within the function. I have tried

echo "$area";
echo "calculatearea ()";

ive searched but still cant figure out how to get a print within the function only outside of it.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['CalcBT'])) {
    global $area;
            function calculateCircumference () {
                 $num1 = ($_POST['Length']);
                 $num2 = ($_POST['Width']);

                $circ = $num1 + $num2;
                return $circ;


                }

                function calculateArea () {
                    $num1 = ($_POST['Length']);
                    $num2 = ($_POST['Width']);

                    $area = 2*($num1 + $num2);
                    return $area;

                }
    echo "Your rectangle circumference is: " . calculateCircumference() . '<br />' . "Your rectangle area is: " . calculateArea();
}

?>

<!---------------- Form---------------->

    <div class="form">

        <h3></h3>

        <form action="PHP-sida4.php" method="POST">
            <p>Length: <input type="text" name="Length"value=""></p>
            <p>Width: <input type="text" name="Width"value=""></p>

            <input type="submit" name="CalcBT" value="Calculate">
        </form>
```

I need the return value of $area along with what I echo'd in the bottom to actually print within the first function ( calculateCircumference )

Comment: Pass `$area` as parameter to the function: `function calculateArea($area) { ... } `

Comment: @FelippeDuarte  How would you pass a value to a function that calculates _that value_?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte bit confused on that as its the same thing no?

Comment: He is using `global $area`, I guess he already have it somewhere.

Comment: ` $num1 = $_POST['Length'] ?? 0` would set $num1 to 0 if not defined without any warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo anything you want within the function but it won't show up until you call the function.

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['CalcBT'])) {
   global $area;
   function calculateCircumference () {
    $num1 = ($_POST['Length']);
    $num2 = ($_POST['Width']);

    $circ = $num1 + $num2;

    // return $circ;
    echo "Your rectangle circumference is: " . $circ . '<br />' . "Your rectangle area is: " . calculateArea();
    return;

  }

  function calculateArea () {
    $num1 = ($_POST['Length']);
    $num2 = ($_POST['Width']);

    $area = 2*($num1 + $num2);
    return $area;

  }

  calculateCircumference();
}

?>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: omfg... that worked I feel so fing stupid. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Glad to help! Can you please accept my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Okay if am getting your question right, to need to return the area and some other text along with the area.

Let's begin with some house cleaning, therefore the `$area` global variable could be renamed to something else like `$results` Which will be an array or object. Taking it simple.

Lets go with an associative array where e.g:

```
$results = [
    'area' => null,
    'text' = null
];
```

From that your will be updating `$results['area']` from the calculate function and also update the `$results['text']` before calling echo, so probably extract the echoed text to another variable.

And now you can access $results anywhere within the file with both the area and the text:

To just be more expressive under `CalculateArea()` function do something like:

```
$results['area'] = $area;
```

Same thing with the echoed text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `echo` instead of `return` in your functions. To call them, your can just use `function();` without any additional keyword :

```
function calculateCircumference () {
    $num1 = ($_POST['Length']);
    $num2 = ($_POST['Width']);

    $circ = $num1 + $num2;
    echo $circ;
}

function calculateArea () {
    $num1 = ($_POST['Length']);
    $num2 = ($_POST['Width']);

    $area = 2*($num1 + $num2);
    echo $area;
}

echo "Your rectangle circumference is: " ;
calculateCircumference() ;
echo '<br />' ;
echo "Your rectangle area is: " ;
calculateArea();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `echo` anything anywhere, be it inside a function or outside of it. If an `echo` is not performing, then there was either an error, or the line where the `echo` can be found was not executed.

In our case you have removed the `echo` after your functions, which, coincidentally happened to be the only place where they were called.